# Can I dockerize only Django (backend) with React JS (frontend) rendered on same server as Django runs on?

Tags: django, reactjs, docker-compose

I've developed Django as backend with ReactJS as frontend being served on Django server (127.0.0.1:8000) by putting frontend folder inside backend folder and using static files with path to build/static of frontend in settings.py. So I'm able to run reactjs app on localhost:8000. That's fine.

Now question is if it's possible to dockerize only Django backend, which will have everything including frontend contents and run single docker container opening react js app? Or shall I dockerize frontend as well separately?

Looking forward to your inputs.

Regards

Please note that I've also done with both backend and frontend running separately on 2 servers (localhost:8000 and localhost:3000), used docker-compose to build 2 dockerfiles and them talking each other. So my above q is about possibility to dockerize only backend as a single container image which has frontend static files inside.

Comment: Yes, various combinations like what you describe are possible, including using tools like Webpack to compile the front-end application into static files.  Is there a specific setup you're having trouble with?